# "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError" error?

Tags: java

When I'm trying to call a method from another class in my main method, I am coming across the error which is described in that title. The error points to the third line of my class TestCalculator. Here is the code:

**TestCalculator class**

```
public class TestCalculator {
        Double x;
       TestCalculator c = new TestCalculator();
 String string = "b";
 Double doubleObject = 1.0;
 double doublePrimitive = 2;


        /*
        * Chops up input on ' ' then decides whether to add or multiply.
        * If the string does not contain a valid format returns null.
        */
        public Double x(String x){
            x("12 [ 3");
                return new Double(0);
        }
        public void testParsing() {

         if (c.x(doubleObject) == 17) {
            System.out.println("Adding Success");}
            else {
                    System.out.println("Adding Fail");
                    }
         if (c.x(doublePrimitive) == 60) {
            System.out.println("Multiplying Success");}
            else {
                    System.out.println("Multiplying Fail");
                    }
         if (c.x(string) == null) {
            System.out.println("Valid operator Success");}
            else {
                    System.out.println("Valid operator Fail");
                    }
        }
        /*
        * Adds the parameter x to the instance variable x and returns the answer as a Double.
        */
        public Double x(Double x){
                System.out.println("== Adding ==");
                x("12 + 5");

                return new Double(0);
        }
        /*
        * Multiplies the parameter x by instance variable x and return the value as a Double.
        */
        public Double x(double x){
                System.out.println("== Multiplying ==");
                x("12 x 5");

                return new Double(0);
        }
}
```

**Main class**

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {

TestCalculator call = new TestCalculator();
call.testParsing();

}   
}
```

I'm not too sure as to why this error is occurring. If somebody could help me understand what this error is and why it is happening, that would be much appreciated by myself and anybody else who may also come across this issue in the future. Thanks.

Comment: You are calling the function over and over without end, what result do you expect?

Comment: I'm confused on how to assign a value to each method and then call that method in the main method. As all the methods have the same name, this is confusing me on how to differentiate between those methods.

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: It's okay now it seems to be working. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Assign a value to a method?  That doesn't even make any sense!

Comment: Ah didn't mean to say value I meant to say variable sorry. Been a long day...

Answer (score 1):

To fix this particular problem, eliminate line 3, and get rid of any reference to `c` in your code.  Where you say things like `c.x(doubleObject)`, you should instead just use `x(doubleObject)`.  What you are building is, itself, a `TestCalculator`, so there is no need to create another `TestCalculator` *inside* of it.

That will fix the error you're having, but it will also immediately bring you to other errors that are pretty similar in nature.

On a very basic level, don't call a function within itself (like calling `x` within `x`) yet.  That's a specialized technique called *recursion*, and it's not going to help you here.  Additionally, don't give your function the same exact name as the parameter being passed in.  By this, I mean that instead of

```
public Double x(String x)
```

you might use something like

```
public Double choose(String command)
```

Otherwise, you will get confused between the two different uses of `x`.

Within a function like `choose`, you have to work with the String provided, `command`, and use if statements and Java's String functions to figure out what `command` requires.

Answer (score 1):

You can distill your `TestCalculator` class down to the following, which still gives the `StackOverflowError` (this is what is meant by a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)):

```
public class TestCalculator {
  TestCalculator c = new TestCalculator();
}

public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    new TestCalculator();
  }
}
```

When you compile `TestCalculator`, the compiler converts this to something like the following:

```
public class TestCalculator {
  TestCalculator c;

  public TestCalculator() {
    c = new TestCalculator();
  }
}
```

Think about what happens: in the constructor of `TestCalculator`, you're creating a new instance of `TestCalculator`, which will invoke the constructor of `TestCalculator`.

But in invoking the constructor of `TestCalculator`, you create  a new instance of `TestCalculator`, which will invoke the constructor of `TestCalculator`.

And in invoking the constructor of `TestCalculator`, you create  a new instance of `TestCalculator`, which will invoke the constructor of `TestCalculator`....

etc etc etc. If you create one instance of `TestCalculator`, you just keep on creating instances of `TestCalculator`, each time pushing one more frame onto the stack. Eventually, you run out of space on the stack, and you get a `StackOverflowError`.

---

There is no problem with having a reference to a `TestCalculator` inside `TestCalculator`; and there's no issue with invoking `new TestCalculator()` inside `TestCalculator`. The problem is unconditionally invoking `new TestCalculator()` directly or indirectly in the constructor or instance initializers of the class.

The fix is to remove the `TestCalculator c = new TestCalculator();` line from your code; or, at the very least, change it to `TestCalculator c;` (i.e. leave it uninitialized).